# Reshape long data, make the new column names include the name of the original variable

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

Consider that I have this data:

```
foo bar baz   qux
1   1   65    16
1   2   542   16
1   3   832   16
2   1   1818  20
2   2   56    20
2   3   21    20
3   1   684   213
3   2   216   213
3   3   486   213
```

It's in long format, since each `baz` value depends on the `bar` ID. What I need to get is:

```
foo bar_1   bar_2   bar_3   qux
1   65      542     832     16
2   1818    56      21      20
3   684     216     486     20
```

So, I tried all kinds of things with `dcast`, but I can't come up with the right approach:

```
> dcast(data, foo + qux ~ bar, value.var = "baz")
foo qux  1       2   3
1   16   65      542 832
2   20   1818    56  21
3   213  684     216 486
```

This *almost* gets me what I want, but the names of the columns aren't right yet.

What can I do to get the final needed output?

Comment: `data$bar <- paste("bar", data$bar, sep="_")`

Comment: Alternate (assuming you assign the `dcast` to `d2` : `library(data.table); setnames(d2, colnames(d2), c(colnames(d2)[1:2], sprintf("bar_%s", colnames(d2)[3:5])))`. Using `setnames` from `data.table` doesn't copy the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use reshape

```
origdata.long <- read.table(header=T, text='
 foo bar baz   qux
1   1   65    16
1   2   542   16
1   3   832   16
2   1   1818  20
2   2   56    20
2   3   21    20
3   1   684   213
3   2   216   213
3   3   486   213
 ')

reshape(origdata.long, timevar="bar", v.names="baz", idvar="foo", direction="wide", sep="_")
row.names(wide) <- NULL
> wide
  foo qux baz_1 baz_2 baz_3
1   1  16    65   542   832
2   2  20  1818    56    21
3   3 213   684   216   486
```

Comment: That `reshape` is in `stats` so the `require(reshape2)` isn't necessary.

Comment: Very clever. Didn't think something like this was built in. I rephrased my question title to maybe make that more accessible in the future.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, Ah! Thank you, memory was a bit off as to the environment of reshape.  Removed.

Answer (score 2):

In what seems to lie somewhere between a bug and a feature, the RHS of the formula in `dcast` from "reshape2" does not have to be a variable in your source `data.frame`. What that means is that you can do something like the following to get your desired output:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(mydf, foo + qux ~ paste0("bar_", bar), value.var = "baz")
#   foo qux bar_1 bar_2 bar_3
# 1   1  16    65   542   832
# 2   2  20  1818    56    21
# 3   3 213   684   216   486
```

---

Alternatively, the pasting can be handled within `mutate` in "dplyr", which can be used in conjunction with `spread` from "tidyr":

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

mydf %>%
  group_by(foo, qux) %>%
  mutate(bar = paste0("bar_", bar)) %>%
  spread(bar, baz)
# Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
# 
#   foo qux bar_1 bar_2 bar_3
# 1   1  16    65   542   832
# 2   2  20  1818    56    21
# 3   3 213   684   216   486
```

Both of these alternatives would allow you to do the pasting "on the fly" rather than overwriting your original "bar" variable with the pasted values.